# Export Translations for Managed Topics in Salesforce Experience/Community

Tags: lightning-community, translation, translation-workbench, experience-builder-page

I have tried to export translations for **ManagedTopics** in my Salesforce Community using **Export Content** feature as well as **Translation workbench** but I am not able to see the translations I have done for my community site's Managed Topics.
I need to export those translations in either **.stf** or **.xlf** files for translation purposes.
Any ideas how this can be acheived?